# Default assembly info in Visual Studio does not match the registry values

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have followed previous instruction from here and MSDN to change the registry value in regedit.... HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion
specifically company name and copyright company name. However, the assembly info still shows the default "Microsoft". Any ideas on how to get assembly info to accurately reflect the registry?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Fixed my issue... The instructions on MSDN that I listed above only apply to 32-bit versions of Windows. In order for the default assembly values to change on a 64-bit version, you must modify the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion.  Necessary because VS is a 32-bit process.